# How to call javascript function from ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                // THIS IS FOR HIDE ALL DETAILS ROW
                $(".SUBDIV table tr:not(:first-child)").not("tr tr").hide();
                $(".SUBDIV .btncolexp").click(function () {
                    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggle();
                    //this is for change img of btncolexp button
                    if ($(this).attr('class').toString() == "btncolexp collapse") {
                        $(this).addClass('expand');
                        $(this).removeClass('collapse');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).removeClass('expand');
                        $(this).addClass('collapse');
                    }
                });

                function expand_all() {
                    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggle();
                    };
            });

    </script>
```

I want to call `expand_all` function via code-behind .

I know I can use something like this, but it does not work and I don't understand used parameters:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(String), "Error", "expand_all();", True)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: As for the parameters used, they hide that stuff in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have your `expand_all` function defined within anonymous `$.ready` event context. Put your code outside and it should work.

```
function expand_all(){
    alert('test B');
}
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        // this won't work
        function expand_all() {
            alert('test A');
        };
    });


// will show test B
expand_all();
```

check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jrrymg0g/

Answer (score 1):

Your method `expand_all` only exists within the scope of the function inside `$(document).ready(...)`, in order for you to call it from `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` it needs to be at the window level, simply move that function outside the `$(document).ready(...)`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
           ....                
        });

    function expand_all() {
           $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggle();
    };
</script>
```